# OracleDataReader Read() is not responding after a period of time

Tags: c#, oracle, insert

I try to make inserts, reads from a oracledatareader object in c#, I am reading around 50 rows and insert it to db, for 300 times, it is ok till around 150-200. iteration, but after that datareader.Read() stop reading, so cannot insert, what would be the probblem with that ?

thanks

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
while(true)
{              
if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
{
con.Open();
}
OracleCommand transaction = new OracleCommand(@"select * from foos where date=:date", con);
DateTime d=DateTime.now;
transaction .Parameters.Add("date", d);
transaction.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;               
OracleDataReader r =Tansaction.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
 while (r.Read())                    
 {                  
 fooitem = new foo();
 item.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["creationdate"]);
 item.SectionId = dr["sectionId"].ToString();
 InsertSalesItem(item);
 }
 d=d.AddDays(-1);
 }
```

Comment: For what you need this: for (int i = 0; ; )??? Makes it really sense to read the same data everytime and safe them back without change something?

Comment: actually, i know that it is infinite loop, case is different, the application will use just one time, to insert rows. so i know that there are rows but dr.read() does not read. that is my problem.i am changing code, to make it more clear